# XlsxWriter write_formula with date

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am trying to use formula to copy a date value from a cell to another. But trying to add date format to `worksheet.write_formula()` causes the excel to to show the following alert

[image]

Here is a sample code I am using:

```
  import xlsxwriter
  from datetime import date

  workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook("testFile.xlsx")
  worksheet  = workbook.add_worksheet()
  dateFmt    = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})

  worksheet.write(0, 0, date(2018, 12, 26),dateFmt)
  worksheet.write_formula('B1','=A1', dateFmt, date(2018, 12, 26))

  workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chof is correct that a `date()` value isn't accepted as a formula value.

Instead you can convert it to an Excel date, i.e. a number, using the XlsxWriter `datetime_to_excel_datetime()` utility function:

```
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date
from xlsxwriter.utility import datetime_to_excel_datetime

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook("testFile.xlsx")
worksheet  = workbook.add_worksheet()
dateFmt    = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})

worksheet.write(0, 0, date(2018, 12, 26), dateFmt)

excel_date = datetime_to_excel_datetime(date(2018, 12, 26), False, False)

worksheet.write_formula('B1','=A1', dateFmt, excel_date)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the 9th line:

> worksheet.write_formula('B1','=A1', dateFmt, date(2018, 12, 26))

Here you gave `date(2018, 12, 26)` for the last optional argument `value`, but that is not an acceptable format for `value` because the [documentation of XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-result) says

> The `value` parameter can be a number, a string, a bool or one of the following Excel error codes:
>
> (... skip ...)